# JS how to get all img src tags

Tags: javascript, twitter

I want to get the SRC from every `<IMG>` in twitter.

```
let n = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(tip of n){
    console.log(tip.src);
}
```

and it works for other pages, but it doesn't for twitter. Finally I did this;

```
let n = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

function example(){
    for(tip of n){
        if(tip.src == "https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/1f1ea-1f1f8.svg"){
            tip.src = "https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/1f3f3-fe0f-200d-1f308.svg";
        }
    }
}

setInterval(example, 100);
```

With setInterval it works, also, twitter loads stuff dynamically so with setInterval I can get all those new results. (How I could do that without using setInterval?)

Also, for some weird reason, the picture doesn't change. It doesn't update.

Update:

```
function example(){
let n = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(tip of n){
        console.log(tip.style['background-image']);

        if(tip.style['background-image'] == 'url("https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/1f1ea-1f1f8.svg")'){
            tip.style['background-image']= 'url("https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/1f3f3-fe0f-200d-1f308.svg")';
        }
    }
}

setInterval(example, 10000);
```

Now it works perfectly, but how could I get the new data without using setInterval eeeeeeevery time and only call to the function when it's necessary?

Comment: As you have mentioned, "_twitter loads stuff dynamically_" thus we can not get src for all images, but only the images loaded at the current moment.

Comment: @palaѕн But using setInterval I would take the new results, right? The point is, even if I'm able to take the src, I can't change it for some weird reason

Comment: That is happening because twitter set images on div using `background-image: url(...)`.

Comment: @palaѕн lol, you're right. How could I get access to that div? I mean, every div has the same name class

Comment: @palaѕн Okay, fixed, it works nice now, what about the setInterval? (I updated the post)

Answer (score 1):

You have to load image every time you want to iterate them, to get "fresh" img elements

Try this

```js
function example(){
    let n = document.getElementsByTagName("img");  // Moved here
    for(tip of n){
        if(tip.src == "https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/1f1ea-1f1f8.svg"){
            tip.src = "https://abs-0.twimg.com/emoji/v2/svg/1f3f3-fe0f-200d-1f308.svg";
        }
    }
}

setInterval(example, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not always that the images are shown with `img` tag.

If you see some cases on twitter, `img` tag's sibling is an element with `img` `src` in its styles. That element is showing the image. Obviously, this is not the case with every single image on twitter.

But for such a case, you change it's background by

```
let n = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(tip of n){
    r.previousSibling.style.backgroundImage='YourImage.png'
}
```

Also, you have to use some kind of interval to get results that are loaded later. Or you could detect DOM changes using [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and only fire your function on DOM change.